# How do I create a custom login url for Facebook graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get the user name and creds from a Facebook user so he can authenticate as a user against my application.  Right now, getLoginUrl returns a site at Facebook, which works.  How do I avoid the user jumping from my site to Facebook?  Can I show a custom form to get the username and password and send that to FB directly?

Comment: You can't build a custom form to post data somehow. The only way is to open the Auth Dialog in a pop up window.

Comment: How do I open the auth dialog in a popup window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `FB.login` function from the Javascript API for this,

```
function fbAuth() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
        alert('User fully authorize the app.');
      } else {
        alert('User canceled login or did not fully authorize the app.');
      }
    }, { scope: 'email,friend_likes' });
}
```

then you can call it with an onclick event or any other method you want:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return fbAuth();">Login</a>
```

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/